# how to run Django web app locally in Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I am following this instruction to run my django project locally
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#run-the-app-locally

When I type heroku local web, it says "[FAIL] No Procfile and no package.json file found in Current Directory - See run-foreman.js --help".
However, my project is a Django/python app and I don't have package.json.
But my project does have requirements.txt and Procfile in the root directory of my web application. What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your project directory structure, as well as the command you ran and the full traceback of the error message that you got in the terminal? We need more details in order to be able to help.

Comment: https://github.com/hkbluesky/heroku/blob/master/26555DE0-10DA-4FEB-8EFA-3A3B3BFB7708_4_5005_c.jpeg

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Please see the above link for a screenshot. I run "heroku local" in the same directory as requirements.txt. Thanks